# ASP.NET Deploying websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, web-services, imagemagick

I have some websites that use ImageMagick to convert images and place them in a created folder. Locally it all worked fine, but once I deployed it to my network's webserver it would not convert the images nor create the folders. My asp.net pages that read data from a database work. All the users have full control permissions over the site. 
I don't know if I need to modify the Web.config or some other permissions. Maybe it has to do with ImageMagick. I've just run out of ideas on what the problem could even POSSIBLY be.
Any suggestions?

/*** SOLVED ***/

I used System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; to get the user identity, which was NETWORK SERVICE. Then I granted this user full control and the folders are now being created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out which identity is running your web site. For doing that find out the AppPool of your web site and get the identity which is running the AppPool. Normally it will be NetworkService or AspNet user.

Now grant this identity access to your Network Image server.

Comment: Thank you! I used System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
to get the user identity, which was NETWORK SERVICE. Then I granted this user full control and the folders are now being created. Images are not being converted, however, and I'm thinking this has to do with a clash between the 64/32 bit environments with the ImageMagick software.

Comment: No errors. I have a try/catch on the conversion calls to ImageMagick and it doesn't catch anything, but I'm not getting the images in the folders. I actually granted Everyone full control on the webserver.

Comment: ImageMagick was not correctly installed with the right version of ghostscript on the server the application was deployed to. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

some error message could help, does the ASP.net user has permission to write or create new folders?

Comment: no error messages are shown, it is supposed to create xml from data and convert images and place them in a folder. it creates the xml but the images and folders are not appearing. The user does have permissions to write to the file